# JSON Decode While/Foreach

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON data saved in the database. I want to put this data in a while loop and get everything in the line, but I can't. How can I do it?

```
[{"count":33226,"info":"","name":"cash","slot":1,"type":"item"},{"count":1,"info":{"telno":"0662052408","isim":"Bob Brc","aitlik":"steam:1100001179c1b7d","durum":"kilitli"},"name":"phone","slot":2,"type":"item"},{"count":1,"info":{"uniqueId":"3_1","keyData":"z6VAhfL3ppApIXR"},"name":"motel_key","slot":3,"type":"item"},{"count":1,"info":[],"name":"ballasbandana","slot":10,"type":"item"}]
```

```
$inventory = $karakter['inventory'];
$inventoryjson = json_decode($inventory, true); 
$items = $inventoryjson['name'];
```

The way it is in my database above, there are more than one item here, but I could not separate them and put them in a loop. The code field at the bottom is also the PHP field.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO,`inventoryjson` is an array so just put a `foreach` loop throw the `inventoryjson`

Comment: try `$inventoryjson[0]['name'];` and you will see your error :) Or use `print_r($inventoryjson)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from this json is a multidimensional array, which means the `$items = $inventoryjson['name'];` will produce an error.

You could use a foreach loop to get the correct info, like so:

```
$inventory = $karakter['inventory'];
$items = json_decode($inventory, true);

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $name = $item['name'];
}
```